# How to solve this: The server tag is not well formed

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I've a hyperlink in aspx page. I edit it like this:

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="hypDuzenle" runat="server" 
         NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("javascript:window.open('~/User/K/KPrintForm.aspx?
                    CD={0}&CT={1}&W={2}&SN={3}&MNR={4}&PNF={5}&MDT={6}',
                    'MsgWindow', 'width=200, height=100')", Eval("B_CD"), Eval("B_CZ"), 
                     Eval("B_WE"), Eval("B_SE"), Eval("MAT"), Eval("SAT"), Eval("MAN"))%>' 
                     ImageUrl="~/img/printer.png">
 </asp:HyperLink>
```

However I get this error message:

> Parser Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>   Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Where can be the problem?

Comment: Where does this HyperLink located? Are you using inside GridView?

Comment: Yes, the hyperlink is located in DevExpress AspxGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution for this error is to set the value in code behind.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypDuzenle" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/printer.png">
</asp:HyperLink>

protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink hypDuzenle=(HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hypDuzenle");

        string B_CD = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "B_CD"));
        string B_CZ = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "B_CZ"));
        string B_WE = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "B_WE"));
        string B_SE = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "B_SE"));
        string MAT = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "MAT"));
        string SAT = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "SAT"));
        string MAN = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "MAN"));      

        hypDuzenle.NavigateUrl="#";
        hypDuzenle.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("javascript:window.open('"+ResolveUrl("~/User/K/KPrintForm.aspx")+"?CD={0}&CT={1}&W={2}&SN={3}&MNR={4}&PNF={5}&MDT={6}','MsgWindow', 'width=200, height=100')", B_CD, B_CZ, B_WE, B_SE, MAT, SAT, MAN));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained for both code snippets what you changed and/or why you think the code would help. Don't just give people a fish, teach them how to fish :-)

Comment: I get this error: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Comment: New window opened, ok. However the main page content disappears and there is a text that is [Object] in the page. How to hold my main page content?

Comment: ok, to hold main page content need to assign onclick instead of NavigateUrl. Let me update code

Comment: Thanks. In addition, how to define scrollbars, addressbar visibilities and not resizable settings?

Comment: You need to pass more parameter in  window.open('/pageaddress.html','winname','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350');

Answer (score 0):

**Replace the asp:hyperlink with a normal html tag link:**

```
<a href='<%# String.Format("javascript:window.open('~/User/K/KPrintForm.aspx?
                    CD={0}&CT={1}&W={2}&SN={3}&MNR={4}&PNF={5}&MDT={6}',
                    'MsgWindow', 'width=200, height=100')", Eval("B_CD"), Eval("B_CZ"), 
                     Eval("B_WE"), Eval("B_SE"), Eval("MAT"), Eval("SAT"), Eval("MAN"))%>'><img src="~/img/printer.png">
         </a>
```